# Messed up by installing GUI on WSL (xfce)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux

a few weeks ago I wanted to add GUI(xfce4) in my WSL. then it didn't work as I expected, so I tried to uninstall it. I guess I didn't know correct way to uninstall it so it still have updates for me. i made a backup of sources list and generated new sources list. But it is still in there. what do you suggest?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport apport-gtk bluez bluez-obexd bsdutils fdisk gcc-8-base gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 ibus ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 libasound2 libasound2-data libatomic1 libblkid1 libbluetooth3 libcc1-0 libfdisk1
  libgcc1 libgd3 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libgomp1 libibus-1.0-5 libitm1 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 liblsan0 libmount1 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libsmartcols1 libstdc++6 libtsan0 libuuid1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 linux-base
  mount python3-apport python3-problem-report util-linux uuid-runtime vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny xxd
49 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 35.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4323 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/b8YRQnCBks/

Answer (score 0):

After you uninstall test with `sudo apt autoremove`. But the best way is to wipe the distribution going to Settings->Apps->Ubuntu and click the Reset button or uninstall and install.

This is a good guide to configure Xfce with WSL. https://x410.dev/cookbook/wsl/customizing-xfce-desktop-for-ubuntu-wsl/ Adapt it to your own XServer.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with removing or updating the packages as WSL automatically manages the updates. Also, if you are trying to run GUI like xfce4, then it won't meddle with your running xfce4.

Just install xfce4 again. If any required packages are already installed, it will automatically manage them and install the necessary. There is no need to reinstall the Ubuntu app.

P.S: Go for WSL 2 as it is more faster and has higher compatibility and runs xfce4 smooth. For this, I found the following link useful: https://autoize.com/xfce4-desktop-environment-and-x-server-for-ubuntu-on-wsl-2/

Also, use Xming or VcXsrv for X server as they are free and open source.